# IIS HTTP Error 403.18 - ASP.NET MVC 3 (with PHP 5.3 installed?)

Tags: php, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error when I am setting up a ASP.NET MVC3 application onto an IIS server.

```
HTTP Error 403.18 - Forbidden

The specified request cannot be processed in the application 
pool that is configured for this resource on the Web server.
```

However the strange thing comes from below; detailed error information:

```
Module IIS Web Core

Notification

BeginRequest

Handler
PHP53_via_FastCGI

Error Code
0x00000000

Requested URL
http://localhost:80/index.php?q=OCOM/Account/LogOn

Physical Path
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php

Logon Method
Not yet determined

Logon User
Not yet determined
```

Is there some kind of 'misconfiguration' whereby the PHP engine somehow interpreted the ASP.NET MVC3 request into a php one? Frankly I don't really understand what went wrong as my local machine works fine with a similar setup (installed PHP, etc. using Microsoft Web PI)

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you have URL Rewrite setup in the root of your website for index.php.

So, if you're running your MVC application in a subdirectory, you can unregister that index.php URL rewrite for that subdirectory.

To do this, just open up IIS manager, click on the subdirectory under your website, and use the "Filter:" box to type "rewrite" and it'll let you get into the URL Rewrite config area.

Then you'll probably see a rewrite rule listed there that you'll want to select (click once) and hit "Disable rule" on the right.

OK?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Handler mappings for that site/directory.  You should see an entry for PHP53_via_FastCGI.  This should remove the FastCGIModule.

...or you can just add this to your web.config

Or you can just add this to your web.config

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
</handlers>
```

This should work for any handler.  Some of you might be getting for a different version or different handler complete.  Just replace "PHP53_via_FastCGI" with whatever it is. (ex. PHP60_via_FastCGI)